How do I add a tag at the end of each line of a file?
My project is here: github
How do I replace the tag at the end of each line in the file?
I'm trying to do it this way:
    rn=l.join([l.strip() + tags[4]])
    fe.write(rn)

But as a result, in the file editor.txt I get a repeat of the line and only then
$ cat text.txt
$ cat settings.py
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
...
$ cat py.py
# fr - read file
# fo - output file
# fw - write file
# l - line
# rt - replace tab
tags=["<p>","</p>","<strong>","</strong>","</br>","&nbsp"]
#print(tags[2])
fr = open("text.txt", "r") 
#fo=fr.read()
#print(fo)
fe = open("editor.txt", "w")
#fe.write(fo)
for l in fr:
    #print(l, end="")   
    rt=l.replace("    ", tags[5])    
    fe.write(rt)
    rn=l.join([l.strip() + tags[4]])
    fe.write(rn)
fe.close()
fr.close()
$ cat editor.txt
$ cat settings.py
$ cat settings.py</br>...
...</br>DATABASES = {
DATABASES = {</br>&nbsp'default': {
'default': {</br>&nbsp&nbsp#'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',</br>&nbsp&nbsp#'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',</br>&nbsp&nbsp'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',</br>&nbsp&nbsp'PORT': '5432',
'PORT': '5432',</br>&nbsp}
}</br>}
}</br>...
...</br>

I generally expect to get such a result in editor.txt:
<p>$ cat settings.py<br />...<br />DATABASES = {<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 'default': {<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 'PORT': '5432',<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; }<br />}<br />...</p>


I generally expect to get such a result in editor.txt:
<p>$ cat settings.py<br />...<br />DATABASES = {<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 'default': {<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 'PORT': '5432',<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; }<br />}<br />...</p>


I'm trying to do it this way:
    rn=l.join([l.strip() + tags[4]])
    fe.write(rn)

But as a result, in the file editor.txt I get a repeat of the line and only then

What is your end goal here? Note that </br> isn't a thing; you're looking for <br> or <br />.

Would the <pre> tag do a lot of the work for you?

If the idea is to "HTML-ify" the data from settings.py, you'll have an easier time if you just read it all, process it, then write it out:
with open("settings.py") as f:
   data = f.read()

data_html = data  # TODO: replace `<` with `&lt;`, etc. here...
data_html = data_html.replace("    ", "&nbsp;").replace("\n", "<br>\n")

with open("output.html", "w") as f:
   f.write(data_html)


The readlines function gives an array of all lines the file contains. You can use it as bellow:
for line in fr.readlines():
  line = line.replace("    ", tags[5])
  line = line.strip()
  line = line + tag[4]
  fe.write(line)

This sample code will operate transformation of each read lines and write the resulting line to you destination file.
NOTE: I kept the transformations separated so that you can link them to your posted sample code.
